# Shifting button image to right in arabic language without transforming the string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton with a string and an image on it. When I open app in arabic, button was still placed on left and string on right, however the string was correctly displayed in arabic.

To move the button to right, I applied transform on the button which moved image on right and string on left which I what I wanted, however it also transformed the string. So the string looks incorrect in arabic. How do I fix it or how do I prevent the string itself from transforming?

***Code:***

```
if isRightToLeftLanguage() {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.customButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
   }
}
```

**Before applying transform:**

[image]

**After applying transform:**

[image]

Comment: This is a layout issue with the image and the text which should be solved by inspecting the layout logic - auto layout would most likely correct for this automaitcally

Comment: ^ Specifically, using autolayout with "leading" and "trailing" anchors over "left" and "right" anchors can help take care of this automatically, since the concept of "leading" and "trailing" follows the text direction, while "left" and "right" are absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the semanticContentAttribute on a view to ask it to draw in rightToLeft. Obviously more to do here with delivering the right attribute but this should get you going.

```
self.customButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

This doesn't cascade down the view stack though, as there are some views that shouldn't be reversed such as playback controls etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use semanticContentAttribute property of button like this:-

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

according to you code it should be

```
if isRightToLeftLanguage() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.customButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
  }
}
```